MockServer with Helm/Kubernetes and random UUID in response
I have a question for using MockServer with Helm & Kubernetes using the instructions here. However, I would like add more configurability using either class callbacks or an expectation initializer class.
So far, I have followed these general steps.

Checkout https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver
Edit helm/mockserver-config/static/initializerJson.json with request/response pairs.
Deploy mockserver with

helm upgrade --install --namespace mockserver mockserver helm/mockserver
helm upgrade --install --namespace mockserver mockserver-config helm/mockserver-config

This works fine for me. However, I would like to use random UUIDs for some return values in the body of a request. The problem at the moment is that I can't rely on hard-coded values because my application writes to a database and these values need to be unique.
When I reviewed the suggestion for extending MockServer classpath, I'm not clear on how this applies in the Helm/Kubernetes case?
For example it has the app.mountedLibsConfigMapName=mockserver-libs. But I'm not clear what this contains?
Is it a jar file with with a single class that inherits from ExpectationInitializer and a main method that does the System.setProperty("mockserver.initializationClass", ExpectationInitializerExample.class.getName()); If someone can point me to an example that would be great.
I would prefer not to have to build another Docker container and instead just rely on the existing Helm chart with an additional library.
